# Efficient ways to check and count zero or one in a vector of logical variables

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, given a vector of logicals, for example, v>0 creats a vector of logicals where v is a numerical vector, what are the efficient ways to respectively

(1) check if there is zero(s) in it?

(2) check if there is one(s) in it?

(3) count how many zeros in it?

(4) count how many ones in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming `v` is a logical vector

(1) `~all(v)` or `any(~v)` is true only if there is at least one zero

(2) `any(v)` or `~all(~v)` is true only if there is at least one one

(3) `sum(~v)` counts zeros (`numel(v)-sum(v)` is faster according to @gnovice)

(4) `sum(v)` counts ones

Comment: For points (3) and (4), i'd rather use the `nnz` function. (3) : `length(v)-nnz(v)` and (4) `nnz(v)`

Comment: @Adrien: NNZ is another option, but it appears to be 10-20 times slower than using SUM.

Comment: For point (3), `numel(v)-sum(v)` appears to be significantly faster than `sum(~v)`, especially for large arrays.

Comment: It seems like a pity that the fastest solutions involve the explicit summation of the elements and not a combination of `numel` and `nnz`

Comment: @Adrien: yes, sometimes it is surprising that the apparently purpose-built functions are slower than alternative approaches. I guess `sum` is just a lot more optimized than `nnz`.

Comment: I guess it depends a lot in  the case, or MATLAB optimized it in the latest versions... nevertheless, I got different results:  I define: `f=rand(1,1e7)>.5;` and then when I run `for i=1:1e2 tic; nnz(f); t(i)=toc; end; mean(t), std(t)` gives ~.33 s while `for i=1:1e2 tic; sum(f); t(i)=toc; end; mean(t), std(t)` gives ~2.29 s